# Forwarding Mouse Events through layers/divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Does anybody know of either a jQuery or native JavaScript way to enable mouse events through layers? e.g. enable a link underneath a `div`.

Other solutions that cannot use in my case:

- [A simple way](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/pointer-events-for-html-in-firefox-3-6/), although using not really supported `pointer-events` (**edit** as of 2017, [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility))
- [An ExtJS solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20161230064952/http://vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

Answer (score 38):

You can do all that or you can just use this CSS for that div:

`pointer-events: none`

Comment: Solution for Internet Explorer is a bit tricky, You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)

Comment: For reference: IE11 does appear to support this property, which is slightly helpful.

Answer (score 19):

I did it once. Here's the code:

```
quickDelegate = function(event, target) {
            var eventCopy = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            eventCopy.initMouseEvent(event.type, event.bubbles, event.cancelable, event.view, event.detail,
                event.pageX || event.layerX, event.pageY || event.layerY, event.clientX, event.clientY, event.ctrlKey, event.altKey,
                event.shiftKey, event.metaKey, event.button, event.relatedTarget);
            target.dispatchEvent(eventCopy);
            // ... and in webkit I could just dispatch the same event without copying it. eh.
        };
```

please note that I was only targeting new versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I run into this problem when using an SVG overlayed over a canvas. Nothing, and I mean nothing else (libraries, CSS or otherwise) could solve this, and this piece of code above was the only thing that works flawlessly! Kudos dear Sir, thank you!

Comment: i also add && (!event.repeat)

Comment: How would you apply this?

Comment: I'm also a little confused as to how to implement this. Can someone explain (or show) it?

Comment: replacing target with event.target I am getting a dispatchEvent is not a function error.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a jQuery implementation of the ExtJS event forwarding script:

[JQuery Forward Mouse Event Example](http://web.archive.org/web/20110713045432/http://e-infotainment.com/applications/jquery-plugins/behaviours/forward-mouse-events/)

Comment: where is the download link or script on that page for `forwardMouseEvents()`?

Comment: dead link... Not sure how useful it is (updated link to use wayback machine).

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Forward Mouse Event example](http://e-infotainment.com/applications/jquery-plugins/behaviours/forward-mouse-events/) given here is part of a larger framework and even just figuring that much out from the given website was a chore.

I therefore rewrote the code as a standalone jQuery plugin.

Here's the Github repository:
https://github.com/MichaelPote/jquery.forwardevents

Unfortunately, the purpose I was using it for - overlaying a mask over Google Maps did not capture click and drag events, and the mouse cursor does not change which degrades the user experience enough that I just decided to hide the mask under IE and Opera - the two browsers [which dont support pointer events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jquery to change the z-index of the div when you hover over it, so that the link is temporarily above the div while hovering over said div.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [JQuery Forward Mouse Event Example](http://e-infotainment.com/applications/jquery-plugins/behaviours/forward-mouse-events/) link is currently dead, I wrote some jQuery code to handle a simple case:

1. overlay div with a transparent image and no links
2. underlay div with links

Goal: keep overlay visible, make links work and cursor change when over a link.

Method: compare the mouse location to each link offset().

I don't handle general mouse events, I just treat the events I need ad-hoc. So it's really a workaround instead of the best solution, which would handle every mouse event abstractly, something like using Wildcard's above quickDelegate() after checking the geometry. Also I only care about certain link elements, not the whole layered DOM.

```js
function mouse_event_over_element(evt, elem) {
  var o= elem.offset();
  var w= elem.width();
  var h= elem.height();
  return evt.pageX >= o.left && evt.pageX <= o.left + w && evt.pageY >= o.top && evt.pageY <= o.top + h;
}

$(overlay_selector).click(function(e){
  $(underlay_selector + ' a').each(function() {
    if (mouse_event_over_element(e, $(this))) {
      // $(this).click(); // trigger a jQuery click() handler
      // quickDelegate(e, this); // not in IE8
      // this.click(); // maybe not in Mozilla pre-HTML5
      window.location.href= this.href;
      return false;
    }
  });
});

$(overlay_selector).mousemove(function(e){
  var newcursor= 'default';
  $(underlay_selector + ' a').each(function() {
    if (mouse_event_over_element(e, $(this))) {
      newcursor= 'pointer';
      // $(this).mouseenter(); // trigger a one-argument jQuery hover() event (no mouseleave)
      return false;
    }
  });
  $(overlay_selector).css('cursor', newcursor);
});
```

Using the geometry function 'mouse_event_over_element()' you can handle other events and elements.

To do: figure out what mouse events trigger the tooltip over `<a title="foo">`, and trigger() them, or replicate showing the tooltip. Same for the status line.

..............................

**Edit 2014/09**

..............................

User user2273627 sggested:

> For the default tooltip and status-line you can use the z-index
>   css-property. Check if the mouse is over a link and set the z-index
>   for that link. $(this).css('z-index','9'); Put an else when the mouse
>   is not over an element and set the z-index to auto. Make sure you set
>   the underlying links position: relative in the css-file, otherwise
>   z-index will not work.