# How to fire mouseenter event when cursor is hidden behind other HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, z-index

I am trying to create draggable chess pieces but I can't find any way to drop a piece on a square because when I hover over a droppable position while dragging a piece then the `mouseenter` event is not firing. I have noticed that `z-index` is the reason because when I put a lower `z-index` on a draggable piece then the `mouseenter` event works but this is not ideal since I can't see a piece that I am dragging anymore.

[image: showing how mouseenter event doesn't fire while dragging]

**Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/hdw3/pen/poNrKpo) that simulates the same behaviour (you have to open a console)**. When mouse enters a black box then `mouseenter` event fires but if mouse enters while dragging a blue box then `mouseenter` event doesnt fire.

Is there a way to force the `mouseenter` or `mouseover` event to fire even when the mouse is hidden behind another HTML element? My goal is to detect when I am dragging over a droppable position so I can move my piece from one `div` to the other.
I have found similar issue in this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614073/how-to-start-mouseover-event-while-dragging) but I really don't like either tracking x-y coords of every droppable `div` or creating transparent element over a droppable `div` with high `z-index` so I am hoping there is a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: Could you make a working snippet so it's easier to see what is going on. Thanks. Also I don't understand this syntax: makeDroppable(element: HTMLElement)

Comment: @AHaworth it isn't plain javascript, I am using typescript and angular. This is just a function that takes HtmlElement as argument. I will try to create a snippet later today

Comment: Thanks, maybe tag the question with the systems you are using so we don't try to interpret it as plain JS.

Comment: @AHaworth I don't see how typescript or angular is relevant here

Comment: @AHaworth I have swaped code from the post for codepen snippet https://codepen.io/hdw3/pen/poNrKpo to avoid confusion. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Forwarding Mouse Events through layers/divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015422/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers-divs), looks like you simply have to modify your `draggable` CSS by adding...

```
pointer-events: none;
```

...so that it becomes...

```
.draggable{
  cursor: grab;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  --size: calc(100% - 2*var(--padding));
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

What does this do?  When the drag starts and applies the `draggable` class to the element being dragged, it turns off mouse events for the dragged element, thus allowing the mouse events to pass through the dragged element to any elements underneath.

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events for complete list of options and browser support.)