# HTML/CSS: Make a div "invisible" to clicks?

Tags: html, css, events

For various reasons, I need to put a (mostly) transparent `<div>` over some text. However, this means that the text can't be clicked (eg, to click links or select it). Would it be possible to simply make this div "invisible" to clicks and other mouse events?

For example, the `overlay` div covers covers the text, but I would like to be able to click/select the text through the `overlay` div:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div id="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0;
                             left: 0; width: 100%; height:100%">
        ... some content ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The short answer is no. (Has been discussed several times, but dupes are hard to find for this, can't think of good keywords...) What do you need the transparent DIV for?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Maybe you tell about the "various reasons" i.e. what you really want to achieve?

Comment: @Null I'd withhold the -1 until it's clear what the OP wants to do.

Comment: NullUserException - How would what he is proposing stop people from copying content from his website? If anything, he is trying to do the opposite - he wishes to obviate the effect of his transparent div (of making text harder to click and select).

Comment: @Hammer You are right. I removed the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. So you know, the strongest of the "various reasons" is that "it will make life (and positioning elements) a whole lot easier. I didn't mention it in the question, though, because I know that I *could* do it other ways, but I'd like to see if it's possible *this* way.

Comment: Here's one of the older questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401658/html-overlay-which-allows-clicks-to-fall-through-to-elements-behind-it/3538713#3538713

Answer (score 200, accepted):

It can be done using CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/pointer-events). This property is supported in Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 2+, IE 11+, and Safari 4+. Unfortunately, I don't have knowledge of a cross-browser workaround.

```css
#overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that looks good! Now, the only problem is that I've got to make some of the children *accept* pointer events… But maybe I can figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: Cool: `pointer-events: visible` looks like it'll do *exactly* what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Works in chrome! Love that this is possible!

Comment: There's a pointer events polyfill: https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by refiring the event after you temporarily hide the overlay.

See the first answer to this question: 
[HTML "overlay" which allows clicks to fall through to elements behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401658/html-overlay-which-allows-clicks-to-fall-through-to-elements-behind-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hiding the overlay like this:

```
overlay.onclick = function(){
    window.event.srcElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var BottomElement = document.elementFromPoint((navigator.appName.substring(0,3) == "Net") ? e.clientX : window.event.x,(navigator.appName.substring(0,3) == "Net") ? e.clientY : window.event.y);
    window.event.srcElement.style.visibility = "visible";
    BottomElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery

```
$("div").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

replace "div" with the ID or element

Answer (score -1):

Alternative for disabling all events(or chick) on a div is unbind() all event that are attached with tags by default

```
  $('#myDivId').unbind();
```

or

```
  $('#myDivId').unbind("click");
```

Comment: `jquery` now uses `off()` in favor of `unbind()`, and only removes the handlers, doesn't prevent the div from capturing the click.