# Mouseover Change Image Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I have a big grid of images. When a user mouseovers an image I want the image to tint blue 0000FF. Is there a way to do this in JS or jquery? Ideally, I wouldn't have to apply a class to each image. This treatment should affect all images on the screen.

After searching the forums here and elsewhere I learned that some folks use a div over the image that has a color and opacity, but how would I apply that to all img?

Another thing I keep seeing is paintbrushJS and pixastic but I don't know how to make those work for this purpose.

Here's the page I'm working on:
http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/

**EDIT: the images need to be be clickable so the div can't obstruct the linked img. Is there a way to click through the div or put the div below or something? Some solutions offered don't use a div but I can't figure them out.**

Thanks!
Rollin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you're gonna want to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ztKJB/1/

**Javascript / jQuery:**

```
$overlay = $('#overlay');

$('img').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.not('.over')) {
        $this.addClass('over');
        $overlay.css({
            width  : $this.css('width'),
            height : $this.css('height'), 
            top    : $this.offset().top + 'px',
            left   : $this.offset().left + 'px',
        }).show();
    }
}).bind('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('over');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/rgb-dots-olan3.jpg" width="150" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/rgb-dots-olan2.jpg" width="150" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/IMG_3291.jpg" width="225" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/1153-1188.jpg" width="200" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/P1010036.jpg" width="200" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/dressRehearsal.jpg" width="267" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/sinWave.jpg" width="225" height="150"
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/mockUp2.jpg" width="225" height="150">
<img src="http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/zzzthumbs/JPEG/PICT0453.jpg" width="113" height="150">
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!!! I'm getting a real education here at stackoverflow. I had this all figured out in Flash, but the result was too heavy and wasn't as easy to update. Piecing my site back together in html has really opened my eyes.

Comment: I have a problem though... Now the links aren't clickable since the div covers it. Is there a way to avoid that problem? I've updated the page.

Comment: @Rollin: Add `pointer-events: none;` to the CSS definition of `#overlay` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538489/html-css-make-a-div-invisible-to-clicks).  I have updated the linked jsfiddle with the changes.  The first image links to Google.  However, I don't think this is fully cross-browser solution.

Comment: @mellamokb Jesus, I love stackoverflow. The links that spun off of that one were very informative as well. Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using a div over the image would work.  You can generate the div on-the-fly as needed (or generate a hidden div to reuse throughout the page), and position it over the image during the onmouseover event:

```
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    // generate a div
    // position over current image
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I think McHerbie is doing just that, right?

Comment: @Rollin: Yep. His answer is brilliant!

Comment: What do you think about roryf's answer? I can't seem to make McHerbie's thing work while keeping the links. The div hides the links.

Answer (score 1):

Append a `span` inside each anchor, and adjust it's opacity on hover:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).appendChild('<span class="overlay" />');
    });
});
</script>

<style>    
    a {
        position: relative;
    }

    a .overlay {
        background-color: #00f;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    a:hover .overlay {
        opacity: 0.4; /* adjust to suit */
    }
</style>
```

Note: you'll need to adjust your styles so the anchors are being `float`ed rather than the images.

If you wanted a fade in/out, you could either use [CSS3 transitions](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions) or hide the `span` initially and use a jQuery mouseover event to fade it in:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).appendChild($('<span class="overlay" />').hide()).hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks excellent. I just can't get it to work. I tried deploying your solution here: http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/index3.php What do you think I'm messing up?

Comment: You need to put it in a document.ready handler, will update answer

Answer (score 0):

This jquery plugin should do the thing you asked pretty well. (tancolor.js)

```
$("#myImageID").tancolor({mode: "blue"});
```

There's an interactive [demo](http://nicolaisi.github.io/tancolor/). You can play around with it.

Check out the documentation on the usage, it is pretty simple. [docs](https://github.com/nicolaisi/tancolor)