# Preventing multiple clicks till record is deleted

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, click

I have a HTML table. For each row there is a record in the database, also on each row I have a delete button (image icon).

On delete I use Ajax request to delete the record from the database
On success, I display a message and I hide()/remove() the row from the table.

It works fine. **BUT if I click real FAST on multiple rows**, the records get deleted ok, but some of the rows are still displayed.

I have my click function attached to a class

```
$(".tog").click(function(e){ ...
```

I already read about jQuery's "toggleClass(), delay()", those did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos plugin while ajax request is going on.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:false,
    beforeSend: function() {
       $('#content').block({ 
              message: ''
            }); 
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#content').unblock(); 
    },
    success: function() {}
    });
```

replace #content with you master div ID

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended, but with [Jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can use an option of `async:false`.

By this, the user wont be able to perform any action on the browser, but the browser may temporarily appear to be hung.

You can also consider displaying an [`overlay`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538489/html-css-make-a-div-invisible-to-clicks/3538639#3538639) to the user, until your request is completed. By this the browser wont be hanged and you can display some in-progress message to the user too.

Answer (score 0):

In function click you disable events

```
$(".tog").click(function () { $(this).unbind() ...
```

Activate after if necessary