# How create a transparent layer without restrict 'click', 'hover' and 'select' events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In current [Github](https://github.com/) website, there is a toggle ability to show/hide the profile menu. on the following screen-shot, there is a `transparent layer` with full width and height behind the menu and if for example I click on "Explore", my first click will trigger the `onclick` event on the transparent layer and it only will hide the menu and transparent layer itself. Then I need to click again on "Explore" to make action.

[image]

but in current [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) website, there is similar toggle ability without above limitation and when the menu is open, I can act like a normal webpage without any limitation to `Select`, `Hover` and `click`.

[image]

In both of websites when you click around, the menu will close, but I could not find any `transparent layer` in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and I am not sure these are using the similar way.

As I know there is several ways to solve these problems:

### [Simulate a click by using x,y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

It is not the correct answer, because in this way, it is not possible to use `hover` like what [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is doing now (you can `hover` over any objects behind the menu).

### [Make an element “invisible” to clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538489/html-css-make-a-div-invisible-to-clicks)

It is not the correct answer, because in this way, it is not possible to use `onclick` event to hide menu itself.

### [JavaScript to prevent Default action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017184/4991669)

It is not the correct answer, because in this way, it is not possible to use `hover` and `onclick` events at the same time. then it is not possible to make it like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Can you please guide me how [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is passing the [Github](https://github.com/) limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't create a transparent overlay at all.

Instead listen for the `click` event on `document` and close the menu if it's fired.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('button clicked')
})

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('click reached document, close menu')
})
```

```html
<div>
 <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to toggle menu using classes like this:

when it is close:

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
```

when it is open:

```
<div class="menu open">...</div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.menu {
    display: none;
}

.menu.open {
    display: block;
}
```

then you need to add an `onclick` event on the document to find all open menus and remove `open` class of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    document.onclick = closeAllOpenMenus;

    function closeAllOpenMenus() {
        const all_open_menus = document.querySelectorAll(".menu.open");

        [].forEach.call(all_open_menus, function(el) {
            //remove 'open' class
            el.classList.remove("open");
        });
    }
</script>
```

you need to work more on the above function to prevent `closeAllOpenMenus` when the user is clicked over the menu itself.