# Absolutely positioned div over selectable text / links

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div that is positioned over a large chunk of the page, this causes the content underneath the div to no longer be selectable / clickable.

Is there a way to remedy this? ie: make a div not have any clickable functionality to it?

```
#page {
    width: 980px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#overlay {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 536px;
    width: 422px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: -20px;
    background-image: url(../images/overlay_full.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: Yeah doesn't seem like it's possible, thanks though!

Comment: It is possible, I'm going to write an answer in some minutes when I can.

Comment: The technique I'm thinking of requires javascript, is that acceptable?

Comment: I wanted to do this, but I thought "surely this is impossible but I'll at least Google it...".  Glad I was wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the div to overlay the (clickable) stuff below, there is no decent way. An undecent way could be to hide the element on mousedown and reshow it onmouseup:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function() { getElementById("overlay").style = "display:none;" });
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function() { getElementById("overlay").style = "display:block;" });
```

However be warned this is causing a reflow with every mousedown so will hit performance.

Comment: this prevents things like the mouse cursor changing to a hand when hovering over links, and prevents links from being underlined when hovered. The `pointer-events` answer is the right answer, as long as you don't need to support anything older than IE11.

Answer (score 17):

use css attribute "pointer-events" on the overlay:

```
#overlay {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

see: [HTML “overlay” which allows clicks to fall through to elements behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401658/html-overlay-which-allows-clicks-to-fall-through-to-elements-behind-it)

Comment: As the comments on the linked version mention, this is a really nice solution, but you have to be careful since it's not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Awesome! Super clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `z-index` property to make the clickable objects overlap this mask. See how it works here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: But doesn't this defeat the purpose of positioning the thing on top?

Comment: Yeah I pretty much would need all the content to do this which would then hide the div completely

Comment: depends.. you can add z-index to links for instance and those you want to be on top, maybe you can post the relevant html to get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

There is/was a cheat method to do this were you put the overlay in a container div, set to:

```
position:fixed;
overflow:display;
width:0px;
height:0px;
```

Which subsequently causes it to have no hit area, but still be visible. However I don't know if this is cross-browser safe and may in fact be the result of a bug.