# Superimposing a container DIV over its own children

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I've got a somewhat complex JavaScript scrolling view implemented, all contained in a DIV.  The elements inside have handlers for `mouseover` and `mouseout` to control the scrolling behavior, and there are also links inside that can be clicked.

Now, I need a mostly-transparent image which partially (or completely, doesn't matter) covers the scrolling view to be superimposed over everything going on in the scrolling div, while still maintaining the event handling.  I thought the easiest way to do this would be if I could somehow wrap the entire DIV in another DIV whose background image is the image to be superimposed, so that events occurring to the superimposed image can be passed down and captured by the child elements.  I can't seem to find a way to make the container DIV's background render over its contents though--I know this is totally counter-intuitive and anti-DOM, but I really just want to avoid changing my existing JS code just to accommodate this extra image, no matter how hackish the solution.  It would look something like this:

```
<div id="superimposed" style="background-image: url('superimposed.png')">
    <div id="scrolling-view"> ... </div>
</div>
```

I tried various experiments with z-index to no avail.  Is this even possible?  And if not, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Would instead setting the opacity of everything in scrolling-view work?  I would think it would achieve the same result.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @MisterZimbu: what do you mean? @thirtydot: All modern browsers, e.g. most Mozilla, Chrome, Safari, and IE 7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [HTML "overlay" which allows clicks to fall through to elements behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401658/html-overlay-which-allows-clicks-to-fall-through-to-elements-behind-it)

Comment: Thanks, it's kind of messy, but I guess this is the only way