# How can prevent the click on elements which under the transparent overlay div in windows phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am developing a mobile web application using html and javascript.I have a task to develop loading overlay in this application and I have made a transparent div as overlay ,while it po-up need to prevent the click on the elements which is under the transparent div.But only in windows mobile phones (IE browser) it's possible me to click the underlying elements.How I can prevent this? given below the css I have applied for it

```
.overlaypage {
top: 0px;
opacity: .5;
background: black;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
pointer-events: visible;
display: block;
z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 14):

I found this question here first, but I found another SO post that had a CSS-only solution that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931709/1058612).

The gist of the CSS is as follows:

```
.overlay {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  pointer-events: none;
  background:none !important;
}
```

In my case, I had text as well, and I didn't want users to be able to select it, so added the following (see user-select [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)):

```
.overlay {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */    
}
```

Comment: could you explain this answer? the `pointer-events` makes sense, I'm confused about the other attributes.

Comment: The CSS I used came from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931709/1058612) (and that's where the other attrs come from), but it was explained as: _A silly hack I did was to set the height of the element to zero but overflow:visible; combining this with pointer-events:none; seems to cover all the bases._ I added the `user-select` stuff for text.

Comment: this seems to allow tabbing through the iframe elements and you can still fill out a form in there.

Answer (score 4):

Add **onclick** attribure to overlaypage block. Like:

```
<div class="overlaypage" onclick="return false;"></div>
```

Comment: the  bad practice part is discussable - but it does work. The event returns false - and prevents propagation which stops the click event on the item below (by z-index, above by html tree structure)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the z-index to action element.

for more visit here: [Disable Clicks on Div Overlay, But Allow Children Clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704126/disable-clicks-on-div-overlay-but-allow-children-clicks)