# how to access image through div

Tags: javascript, css

if I have a `div` over my `image tag`, how it is possible to keep access to the image through the `div`? I mean when I right click on that div to have options from image tag like `open image in new tab` and so on, or even on left click to have access to the image, but the div should be visible..

I have something like :

CSS

```
myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
   <div>
     <img src="..." alt="..">
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
   </div>
```

*P.S : I saw on some kind of lightbox a zoom icon over images but on right click or on other action I had access to the image, not to the overlay div, as expected.*

Comment: what is your question exactly ?

Comment: See this : [HTML “overlay” which allows clicks to fall through to elements behind it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401658/html-overlay-which-allows-clicks-to-fall-through-to-elements-behind-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found an answer :**

CSS :

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: That's not going to work in IE John.. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie for the discussion on the subject.